TLS handshake Issue program run on Windows 11: Binding Request User No Response
Ｗireshark capture
I am encountering an issue with TLS handshake when I reboot the computer and then first run of a program on Windows 11. The handshake process involves Binding Request User which does not receive a response from client. However, running the program a second time results in a successful handshake.
Steps Taken

Disabled Windows Firewall: The issue persists.
Ensured all Windows updates are installed.
Tested on both wired and wireless connections.

Additional Information

This issue only occurs on Windows 11.
The same program works perfectly on Windows 10.
Rebooting the system and running the program results in the same initial failure.

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!!

Since the issue resolves on the second attempt, it might be related to the initial network stack not being fully initialized after a reboot. Resetting the TCP/IP stack might help.
You can reset it using the following commands in command prompt: netsh int ip reset netsh winsock reset and then restart your computer.
